# Prove that every closed set in R is the intersection of a sequence of open sets in R

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $ A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and for each positive number $n$ define
>   $U_n=\{x\in \mathbb{R};  |x-a|<1/n\ \text{for some}\ a \in A\} $. Prove that:
>   a) $U_n$ is open for all $n.$
>   b) $\overline{\rm A}$ = $\cap_1^\infty U_n$
>   c) Every closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the intersection of a sequence of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$

I can do part a by showing the arbitrary union of open sets is open. For b, I can only show $\overline{\rm A}$ $\subset$ $\cap_1^\infty U_n$ and do not know how to proceed further. And, so, I am unable of coming up with a rigorous proof/explanation for part c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b):

To show the other inclusion, take any $x$ which is contained in every $U_n$.

This means that for any $n$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $|x - a| < \frac 1 n$.

Now for any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $n$ such that $\frac 1 n < \epsilon$, and we see that there exists $a\in A$ such that $|x - a| < \epsilon$. This literally means that $x$ lives in the closure of $A$.

For c):

This is a combination of a) and b).

Comment: For c) I think we'll need the following result too: $A$ is closed if and only if $A=\bar{A}$.